# how to get information from a svg string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, svg

I have a String of a svg drawing. For example my string var has this content:

```
<svg width="612" height="394" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g>
     <title>Layer 1</title>
     <rect id="svg_1" height="152" width="265" y="44" x="91" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000"/>
 </g>
 <g>
     <title>Layer 2</title>
     <rect id="svg_2" height="125" width="151" y="157" x="399" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

is there a easy way to get informations? for example, what is the best way to get the height of the rect? how to select only the height of the rect from the Layer 2? 
Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a xml dom parser.
As stated in other answers, jQuery is a very good solution for manipulating and traversing html/xml :

```
 $(svgString).find('g:eq(1) rect').attr('height');
```

If you don't want to use 3rd party libs, you could do this in plain javascript, but your *svg string* should be appended into the dom :

```
var svgString = a='<svg width="612" height="394" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g>     <title>Layer 1</title>     <rect id="svg_1" height="152" width="265" y="44" x="91" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000"/> </g> <g>     <title>Layer 2</title>    <rect id="svg_2" height="125" width="151" y="157" x="399" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000"/></g></svg>',
    tempElement = document.createElement('div');

tempElement.innerHTML = svgString;
var height = tempElement.querySelector('g:nth-child(1) rect').getAttribute('height');
```

Here's a working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/5K5x2/

Comment: thanks it works.... I have tested $(svgString).find('g:eq(1) rect').attr('height');.

Answer (score 1):

#### Try this?

Include jQuery in your code, and use:

```
$("svg").find("rect").attr("height");
```

---

#### Using strings:

```
var str = "<svg> ... </svg>"
$(str).find("rect").attr("height");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks... my string var is for exemple str = <svg width.......</svg>    I have put str instead of svg in your code but it doesn't work