# change information in svg string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, svg

I have a svg string.
In order to get information, I got the answer in this link [how to get information from a svg string in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070793/how-to-get-information-from-a-svg-string-in-javascript) usign jquery.  But does anyone know how to change any atribute? for example how to change the height of the rect of the Layer 2 to other value? How to add a new attribute which doen't exist? for example to add stroke-dasharray="1,1" in the rect of the Layer 2? Thanks

```
<svg width="612" height="394" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g>
     <title>Layer 1</title>
     <rect id="svg_1" height="152" width="265" y="44" x="91" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000"/>
 </g>
 <g>
     <title>Layer 2</title>
     <rect id="svg_2" height="125" width="151" y="157" x="399" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

My string es for exemple: `str="<svg width........</g></svg>"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set a value to it instead of just retrieving..

With jquery you can use the second parameter of [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) to use a value to be set...

```
$('#svg_2').attr('height', 200);
```

and

```
$('#svg_2').attr('stroke-dasharray', "1,1");
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/FX67f/1/

---

If you want the actual string, and the svg is not in the DOM but just a variable then you can do

```
var fixedstr = $(str).wrapAll('<div>')
                     .find('g:eq(1) rect')
                     .attr('height', 200)
                     .attr('stroke-dasharray', "1,1")
                     .closest('div')
                     .html();
```

First we create a jquery object out of it, and then we wrap it in a `div` element so we can later get its `.html()` (*the actual svg string*).

Find the rect in the second `g` element with `.find('g:eq(1) rect')` and then use the `.attr()` to alter its attributes..

Finally use `.closest('div')` to go back up to our container div, and use `.html()` to get the contents..

**Demo for this version at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/FX67f/2/

Comment: hi, I have tried $(str).find('g:eq(0) rect').attr('height', '200'); There is not error but the height doesn't change.

Comment: @user1872320, `str` in the other answer is a variable holding a selector t find the element.. Do you have an `str` variable and what does it hold? otherwise use the code in the demo i provided..

Comment: str is a string ->  str="<svg width=........</g></svg>" I think your code should be fine but you use id. I have not access to id's. Only I have the string...

Comment: @user1872320, if the `str` is a string, then you will need to put the result in the DOM.. otherwise you are just manipulating an SVG in memory ..

Comment: @user1872320, just noticed you are actually just manipulating a string.. So you do not want to show this on screen, but just change the string ? do you need the edited string ?

Comment: Great!!!, It works...  Now I have a new string updated with the changes... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried that but it should work:
Set a new value:

```
$("svg").find("rect#svg_2").attr("height", new_val);
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried $(str).find('g:eq(0) rect').attr('height', '200'); There is not error but the height doesn't change